# How can I to display first part of string using xslt?

Tags: xslt

How do I display only a specific part of string using xslt, for example:

1. Greatest Hits
2. Picture book

I want to display only Greatest and in second one only picture. Only the first part is to displayed.

Comment: There is no source-XML document provided and no wanted answer. This is too general to qualify for an XSLT question. Please, *edit* the question and provide this important, missing information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the substring function like this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring-before($yourstring, ' ')"/>
```

It only selects the part of your string before the blank.
There is also `substring` and `substring-after`.

It is worth looking into them.